# How to pass the value from v-for to a simple django filter

Tags: django, vue.js

I have the following component in a django template

```
<div class="trow" v-for="(item, idx) in data">
</div>
```

Now if I try to write the following inside the div

```
{{ item.co.name }}
```

I won't get the value, I will have to write the following to get the value

```
{% verbatim %} {{ item.co.name }} {% endverbatim %}
```

Now my problem is that I have to do something with this value so I wrote a simple filter like this

```
from django import template
from django.templatetags.static import static

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def define(val=None):
    return static(f"images/{val.lower()}.svg")
```

but I can't do the following

```
    <div class="trow" v-for="(item, idx) in data">
   {% verbatim %} {{ item.co.name | define }} {% endverbatim %}
    </div>
```

I've also tried a lot of combinations with no luck, how can I solve this?

Edit: I changed the data and added the path I want inside it, now I want to use this value inside an img tag like this

```
<img src="{{ item.icon_path }}">
```

but this again won't give me the value because it needs a verbatim tag, and doing it like this

```
<img src="{% verbatim %}{{ item.icon_path }} {% endverbatim %} ">
```

Comment: Vue handles the parsing/rendering inside `v-for`, this happens client-side so you can't use a Django filter. You will have to set this attribute on the data before you pass it to your the front-end

Comment: so should I change the data shape in order to achieve what I want?

Comment: @lain I've edited my question can you check please